# Create a settings page like the uwp email app one

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i want to create a settings page like the one used in the uwp email app:

[image: Settings A]

[image: Settings B]
I would like to have some general settings like in the first image, so when i click on any of them the page navigates to the selected setting.

Currently im using a navigation view in my MainPage.xaml like the following:

```
   <Page
       x:Class="TestApp.UWP.MainPage"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:local="using:TestApp.UWP"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       x:Name="MainContentPage"
       Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
       DataContext="{Binding Home, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
       mc:Ignorable="d">

        <NavigationView
            x:Name="NavigationView"
            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBaseLowAcrylicWindowBrush}"
            CompactModeThresholdWidth="1280"
            ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="1280"
            IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
            IsBackEnabled="False"
            IsSettingsVisible="True"
            MenuItemsSource="{Binding NavigationItems, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}"
                        ToolTipService.ToolTip="Sign out">
                        <Grid Height="40" Margin="-9,0,0,0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SymbolIcon
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Symbol="People" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="Sign out" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        </NavigationView>
    </Page>
```

I was thinking that i could use a frame that contains the general settings buttons and some sort of command/event binded to them, so when i click on any of them the command/event will call the `Frame.Navigate(pageType)` method

The problems/doubts are:

1. I don't know how i could place the main frame to the right
2. To show the frame only after clicking on the navigationview settings button, should i use the Visibility property?
3. How could i close the settings after clicking in any part inside the window? (except the frame itself)
4. Should i use a frame or is there any other better alternative?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [SplitView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/split-view)?
It is designed exactly for this task.

1. Use PanePlacement property
2. Use IsPaneOpen property
3. It's a default behavior of the splitview (Overlay mode)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what i was looking for